# Update storage qty / Update with (SUM)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, sum

I found multiple answers how to use sum with update but didn't get this right.

I wan't to update storage qty with invoice rows when creating new invoice. I need sum to handle same product in multiple rows. 
Edit: Sometimes I need to add new invoice rows after storage already updated with current ones so I need to mark the rows which are ok and sum new lines and reduce storage again.

With couple of hours googling and a lot of testing I got it somehow working:

```
 UPDATE Storage
 SET StorageQty = StorageQty-(SELECT SUM (InvoiceQty)
           FROM InvoiceRows AS Inv
           WHERE Inv.ProductId = Sto.ItemID
           AND Inv.InvoiceId = #InvoiceId#)
 FROM InvoiceRows, Storage AS Sto
 WHERE InvoiceRows.ProductID = Sto.ItemID
 AND InvoiceRows.InvoiceId = #InvoiceId#
```

The problem is I don't understand anymore how it's actually working and I would need to add Invoicerows.StorageOk IS NULL to where clauses so that it would calculate the sum and update just the rows which are not updated yet. StorageOk is set to 1 with next clause to mark the lines to prevent multiple actions.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of how your example works, or for advice on solving another problem?  It's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I would need to add Invoicerows.StorageOk IS NULL to where clauses so that it would calculate the sum and update just the rows which are not updated yet. But I can't get it right if I just add AND.., I get always 0 rows affected. So I would need help with that but also explanation what I have done might solve it for me.